# Drop foreign key if exists using liquibase in MYSQL

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, liquibase

I'd like to ask, is there a way how to drop foreign key constraint only when it exists? My current changeset looks like this:

```
 <changeSet author="blabla" id="10_1_1">

    <comment>Drop FK DummyFK1</comment>

    <dropForeignKeyConstraint constraintName="DummyFK1" baseTableName="DummyToken" />

</changeSet>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 16):

You need to add `preConditions`. There's `foreignKeyConstraintExists` built-in precondition in `liquibase`.

```
<changeSet id="changeSetId" author="John Doe">
    <preConditions onFail="MARK_RAN">
        <foreignKeyConstraintExists foreignKeyName="DummyFK1"/>
    </preConditions>
    <comment>Drop FK DummyFK1</comment>
    <dropForeignKeyConstraint baseTableName="DummyToken" constraintName="DummyFK1"/>
</changeSet>
```